# Hex to binary issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I am getting the expected output for 1 key but not the other. Assuming my math formula is correct KEYCHARS/2 = hex count * 8 = binary output char count

So in other words my key of 52 in length I should get 208 binary characters

```
key1 = "37dcb292030faa90d07eec17e3b1c6d8daf94c35d4c9191a5e1e"
key2 = "a6c8b6733c9b22de7bc0253266a3867df55acde8635e19c73313"


binkey1 = bin(int(key1, 16))[2:].zfill(8)
binkey2 = bin(int(key2, 16))[2:].zfill(8)

print()
print(len(binkey1))   # output 206 chars
print(len(binkey2))   # output 208 chars
length = len(binkey1)
i = 0
currentbin1 = ""
currentbin2 = ""
xorbin = ""
while i < length :
    
    currentbin1 = binkey1[i]
    
    currentbin2 = binkey2[i]
    
    if currentbin1 == currentbin2 :
        xorbin = xorbin + "0"
    else :
        xorbin = xorbin + "1"

        
    i = i + 1

print("xored bin")
print(xorbin) # output is as desired as far as I can tell but missing bits due to the shorting above
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `zfill()` to fill a binary string that you expect to be 208 characters long.  But you're calling with an argument of 8 instead of 208, per your own math.

changing *only* this:

```
key1 = "37dcb292030faa90d07eec17e3b1c6d8daf94c35d4c9191a5e1e"
key2 = "a6c8b6733c9b22de7bc0253266a3867df55acde8635e19c73313"


binkey1 = bin(int(key1, 16))[2:].zfill(208)
binkey2 = bin(int(key2, 16))[2:].zfill(208)

print()
print(len(binkey1))   # output 206 chars
print(len(binkey2))   # output 208 chars
length = len(binkey1)
i = 0
currentbin1 = ""
currentbin2 = ""
xorbin = ""
while i < length :
    
    currentbin1 = binkey1[i]
    
    currentbin2 = binkey2[i]
    
    if currentbin1 == currentbin2 :
        xorbin = xorbin + "0"
    else :
        xorbin = xorbin + "1"

        
    i = i + 1

print("xored bin")
print(xorbin) # output is as desired as far as I can tell but missing bits due to the shorting above
```

Comment: Thank you the reason I did not check that is I thought the converter did byte by byte filling each set but makes sense if it does not